# Microsoft Access form with a circular reference equation

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

In the picture is my current access form. My issue is that I'm provided with yearly volume when I need average daily volume. I'd like to key in the yearly volume into the "Average Daily Volume" text box and after hitting tab or enter to move to "Industry Segment" it divides that number by 252.

[image: Access Form]

Comment: You can do overlaying textboxes. One textbox(tAvgDailyVol)  on top with the formula `= nz([tYearlyVol])/242` and the other(tYearlyVol)l below it where you key in yearly volume. To show the hidden textbox, you need to add event `onGotFocus`  on tAvgDailyVol and set `tYearlyVol.setFocus`

Comment: Is there no way to do a circular reference with my problem?

Comment: add vba code on `AfterUpdate` . `tbox = tbox /242`.

Comment: Me.Average_Daily_Volume.Value = Me.Average_Daily_Volume / 252

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the AfterUpdate event of the textbox.  In the AfterUpdate event, put something like this:

```
Me.Average_Daily_Volume.Value = Me.Average_Daily_Volume / 252
```